# Code Editor for Windows 10 with named bookmarks?

Tags: web-development

Are there any options for:

- Html, css, and basic web coding editor
- Works on Windows 10
- Freeware
- Ability to create named bookmarks within the coding window
- able to open multiple documents at once
- ability to view code side by side in two pane view
- a clean and modern design to the interface is preferred
- ability to end tags yourself (turn off auto end tags)

Right now I am using [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) by Adobe, it is a good option and 95% of what I am looking for but the bookmarks are unnamed which can be frustrating when working with large documents. Also by default it automatically ends tags, it can be customized to turn them off but takes a bit of customizing.

Brackets Preview:
[image: Brackets preview]